# Backbone Click Event Properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I've used backbone.js '`click`' event here. onClick event, I want to select the clicked HTML element,remove it and add into added list.

I am not able to access all HTML dom element where I have clicked. After getting HTML element.

If I click 'China', The below code would alert '`<li>China</li>`'.

So, How do I access all dom properties ?

Java Script code:

```
var ActionBox = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$("#container"),
        events: {
                    "click #add li": "addItem",
                    "click #alert": "alertHere"
        },
        initialize: function(){     
                _.bindAll(this,"addItem","render");             
                this.render();  
        },
        render:function(){  
                this.prepareActions();          
        },
        addItem:function(ev){
                var ac=$(ev.target).html(); // it doesn't give me "<li>US</li>" after clicking US
                alert(ac);
                },
        prepareActions:function(){          
                    var str="";
                    for(var i=0;i<actions.length;i++)   str+="<li>"+actions[i]+"</li>";                         
                    $("#add ul").append(str);
        }       
    });    
var actionBox = new ActionBox();
```

and HTML code as below:

```
    <div id="container">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="add">      
                <ul>
                 <li>US</li>
                 <li>China</li>
                 <li>UK</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="controls">

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="added">        
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

There are two ul containers, add and added, If I click the element from source, it should be shifted into target container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want to use appendTo - this will remove it and put it into your #added UL

```
$(ev.target).appendTo('#added');
```

Comment: cool.. +1 . It solves problem. but, can you tell, why .html() of jquery can't be operated there?  It means, $(ev.target) doesn't give actual DOM element to me.

Comment: .html() gives you what is inside the element, .get(0) gives you the element itself.  If there are more than 1 elements, use get(1), get(2)

Comment: gr8. $($(ev.target).get(0)).html() gives me what I was curious about :)

Comment: a better way would be to do alert($(ev.target).get(0).outerHTML); - this returns the full HTML value of the first item

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it myself with Backbone 0.9.1, and everything worked fine. Make sure you're including

```
var ActionBox = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#container"),
    ...      
});
```

*after* your HTML is rendered.  Otherwise, you're specifying `$("#container")` before it actually exists in the DOM.  If you do that, jQuery will return nothing therefore setting `el` to an empty array, so your events are will be bound to nothing... Therefore they'd never be called.

Here is a jsFiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/8jyeb/1/ .  Notice that you have to wrap all of the JavaScript in a jQuery DOM Ready handler.  This will ensure the code isn't run until the HTML has loaded.

Comment: what alert did you get kpeel?

Comment: If you click on `US`, it'll say `US` (not `<li>US</li>`).  Try the jsFiddle for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for example, I wanted alert of as $(ev.target).html() as <li>US</li>.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that was the problem.  I thought it wasn't returning anything at all.  My mistake.